# WebSocket messages not sent from Jetty server

Tags: java, websocket, jetty-9

Folks!

I'm implementing a chat web application using WebSocket, but, when running on Jetty 9.1.3.v20140225, just after a connection is established, some messages send from server side aren't being received on client side.  Curiously, this misbehavior occurs for some messages, but others are ok (see my PS at the end).

I've tried both Chrome 33 (that I know uses permessage-deflate extension) and FireFox 28 (that doesnt't) with similar results.  In fact, some messages are received by Chrome, but FireFox receives none.

When application runs on TomCat 7.0.47 it works just fine, so I suspect the problem is with Jetty...

Story told lets see the code for my minimum application that reproduces the problem:

First there is a simple page where you can connect, send a message (and receive a response), and disconnect a WebSocket, by click on correspondent button.

**hello.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Minimum - WebSocket Sandbox</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#connect").click(function() {
            connect();
        });
        $("#send").click(function() {
            send("John Doe");
        });
        $("#disconnect").click(function() {
            disconnect();
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    var wsocket;

    function connect() {
        var base = getAppLocation("ws:");
        wsocket = new WebSocket(base + "/hello");
        wsocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            log("<<< " + e.data);
        };
        wsocket.onopen = function() {
            log("Connection opened.");
        };
        wsocket.onclose = function(e) {
            log("Connection closed.  Reason: (" + e.code + ") " + e.reason);
        };
        wsocket.onerror = function(e) {
            log("Error!");
        };
    }

    function disconnect() {
        wsocket.close(1000, "Closed by user.");
        wsocket = null;
    }

    function send(msg) {
        if ( !wsocket || wsocket.readyState != WebSocket.OPEN ) {
            log("Not connected.");
            return;
        }
        wsocket.send(msg);
        log(">>> " + msg);
    }

    function log(msg) {
        $("#output").append(msg + "<br/>");
    }

    /**
     * This just ajust WebSocket URL ocording to the server serving the page.
     */
    function getAppLocation(proto) {
        if ( !proto ) {
            proto = window.location.protocol;
        }
        else if ( proto == "ws:" && window.location.protocol == "https:" ) {
            proto = "wss:";
        }
        var host = window.location.host;
        var path = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        var base = proto + "//" + host + "/" + path;
        return base;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="connect">Connect</button>
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <button id="disconnect">Disconnect</button>
  </div>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On server side there is a single endpoint that sends a message to the client as soon a connection is opened (commented  out line shows a sample message that is received by a Chrome client). It also echoes messages received from the client.

**HelloEndPoint:**

```
package com.ciandt.helenov.sandbox.websocket.min;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/hello")
public class HelloEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen ( Session session, EndpointConfig conf ) {
        try {
            // this is not received in the client
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText( "o" );

            // this is (but only if client is a Chrome)
            // session.getBasicRemote().sendText( "a[\"100\"]" );
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage ( Session session, String msg ) {
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText( "Hello, " + msg + "!" );
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally there is this pom.xml that packages and runs the web application.  I'm running both Jetty (where the issues shows up) and TomCat (that works just fine) through embedded maven plugins inside Eclipse

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>WebSocket Mininum</name>
  <description>WebSocket Minimum Web Application</description>
  <groupId>com.ciandt.helenov.sandbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>ws-min</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <jetty.version>9.1.3.v20140225</jetty.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.47</tomcat.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
          <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Support to use Eclipse -->
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
          <configuration>
              <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
              <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
              <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Support to run Jetty on Eclipse -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
          </webAppConfig>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <port>9090</port>
          <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
          <systemProperties>
            <appserver.base>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-base</appserver.base>
            <appserver.home>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-home</appserver.home>
            <derby.system.home>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-base/logs</derby.system.home>
            <java.io.tmpdir>${project.build.directory}</java.io.tmpdir>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

That's all!

When running application on Jetty (by calling mvn jetty:run), I ask for connecting a WebSocket (by clicking Connect button on page), the onOpen() method in the endpoint runs and a message is sent back to the client, but it is not received since I expected it to be shown.  When running the same application on TomCat (by calling mvn tomcat7:run), it works quite well.

Anyone had a similar problem?  Anyone has any clue of what is happening?  Can it be a bug on Jetty server?

TIA and regards!

Heleno

---

PS: I intent using Spring and SockJS in my application, but SockJS relays on server sending an "open frame" (just an "o") just after the connection is opened, but as its not received it goes to its fallback giving up WebSocket connection and going for a XHR Streaming.  That's what I'm trying to avoid.  But, since I managed to reproduce the problem without both Spring and SockJS (as shown in the code presented), I've discharged them from any involvement with the issue.